# Case, Variable, and a Bunch of Junk

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a giant list of materials that my customer wants to be able to sort by their size with a parameter (SSRS).

I've tried to filter with SSRS with no success, as well as several failed attempts within my SQL code. The problem is that there are some materials that are straightforward, like '2" X 3/4" PVC SCH80 BUSHING SPIGOT X SOCKET', but others are more like, 'HOSE, DISCHARGE', in which we'll have an "Other" category where this will show.

The case part of my code is where I'm tripping up. Is that even right? Should I be using case or something else? I know the joins and first WHERE is correct. Important to note that the size IS always at the beginning of the description, it'll never be in the middle of the name or anything, but the number of characters does vary, sometimes it'll be something like 3/4" or 2", etc. That final tick (") will always be at the end, too.

```
SELECT MATERIALLEAF.DESCRIPTION

FROM STORERMSTOCK

JOIN MATERIALLEAF ON MATERIALLEAF.MATERIALSID = STORERMSTOCK.MATERIALSID 
JOIN CWCUSTFIELD ON CWCUSTFIELD.TABLEOBJECTID = STORERMSTOCK.MATERIALSID

WHERE (CWCUSTFIELD.CUSTFIELDID = '5')  
    AND CASE@sizes
    WHEN'3/4"' THEN
        (SELECT MATERIALLEAF.DESCRIPTION 
            FROM STORERMSTOCK 
                WHERE MATERIALLEAF.DESCRIPTION LIKE'3/4"%') 
    ELSE
        @sizes
    END
```

I'm expecting to see a list that I can filter by the sizes of the materials, plus another selection with everything that doesn't have a size at the beginning of the description.

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  You have a subquery, but are not referencing the table in the subquery `FROM` clause.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: To split your records into the two lists, you may need something like `WHERE MATERIALLEAF.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%[0-9]%'` to grab only those with a number and then implement one of the following answers to further sort the data into sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . perhaps this is what you want?

```
WHERE CWCUSTFIELD.CUSTFIELDID = '5' AND
      (@sizes IS NULL OR
        MATERIALLEAF.DESCRIPTION LIKE @sizes + '%'
      )
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! It was so obvious now that I see it written out. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.   You can't use a CASE expression to return an entire subquery.

It looks like what you want is more like this:

```
WHERE (
  @sizes='3/4"' AND  MATERIALLEAF.DESCRIPTION LIKE'3/4"%'
) OR 
... whatever you want to do if @sizes != '3/4"'.
```